# How to make fxml property "text : " in JavaFX custom control?

Tags: javafx

I've developing JavaFX custom button. Like this.

```
public class MyButton extends Control{
    private static final String DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS = "satrec-button";
    private Button button;

    public MyButton(){
        getStyleClass().setAll(DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS);
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserAgentStylesheet(){
        return "sample/css/button.css";
    }

    public void setButton(Button button){
        this.button = button;
    }
    public void setText(String text){
        this.button.setText(text);
    }
}
```

I want to use this control in FXML. But original button and label can set text to use " test : " Like this

```
<Button text="Search" textFill="white" prefWidth="130" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1" styleClass="control" fx:id="search_btn" />
```

But `MyControl` can not use this function. I looked up `Labeled` class. I know `text` is a `StringProperty`.

But I don't know what is this, and how can I use. How do I do?? Please, help me.

Comment: You need to have a StringProperty called "text" in your custom control so that you can use it in FXML. Or, you can extend MyButton from Button class.

Comment: Also, if you try to use this in FXML in any of the obvious ways, won't `button` be null when the FXML loader tries to set the text? You should probably ensure that `button` is initialized in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default interpretation of an attribute or child property element of an instance FXML element is that it maps to a JavaFX property in the instance. (Essentially it is relying on the control using the [JavaFX properties pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107).)

In other words, in your FXML snippet:

```
<MyButton text="Search" ... />
```

or, equivalently,

```
<MyButton>
    <text>
        <String fx:value="Search" />
    </text>
</MyButton>
```

`<MyButton>` is an *instance element*, and it causes the `FXMLLoader` to create a new instance of the `MyButton` class, calling the default constructor by default. In either version, `text` (an attribute in the first version, a *property element* in the second) is going to cause the `FXMLLoader` to look for a `textProperty()` method, returning a `WritableValue` instance (for example a `StringProperty`). Assuming it finds one, it will call `setValue(...)` on that `WritableValue`, passing in the string `"Search"`. (See the [FXML documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) for a full description of all this terminology.)

So you just need your `MyButton` class to define an appropriate `textProperty()` method. Since you want this to be the text of the included button, you can just delegate to that button's method:

```
public class MyButton extends Control{
    private static final String DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS = "satrec-button";
    private Button button;

    public MyButton(){
        getStyleClass().setAll(DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS);
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserAgentStylesheet(){
        return "sample/css/button.css";
    }

    public void setButton(Button button){
        this.button = button;
    }

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        if (button == null) { // might be better to write the class so that this is never true?
            button = new Button();
        }
        return button.textProperty();
    }

    public final void setText(String text) {
        textProperty().set(text);
    }

    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `NamedArg` Annotation:

```
public MyButton(@NamedArg("text") String text) {
    this();
    this.setText(text);
}
```

otherwise the fxml doesn't know which constructor argument you mean.

Now can use your Button in your fxml as you asked:

`<MyButton text="Search" ...`.

Comment: would be great to explain the downvote, this approach always worked for me.

Comment: It will work, but it is not the standard approach, and you certainly do not "have to" do this. Your answer should explain the standard way to do this and then, if you want, explain what `@NamedArg` does that that method doesn't do.

Comment: Also, I think unless you make other modifications to `MyButton`, this constructor will always throw a null pointer exception, no?

Comment: ok I see that there are other options, so I corrected the "you have to". A NullPointerExeption is not thrown where I use this approach. and btw, who is defining the 'standard approach' for this? ;-)

Comment: The "standard approach" I referred to is the one defined by the [JavaFX FXML documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html). If you add this constructor to the existing `MyButton` class posted by the OP, it will throw a null pointer exception, because `button` will be null. (Also note that it's generally a bad idea to call a non-final method from a constructor.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Good point with the call of the non-final method.

Comment: Thank you for answer ! I solved it thanks to your solution.